# Permissions for files created by the user and PHP

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu

So I have a user `foo` and the group `www-data` When the user creates a file/directory manually the permissions are:

```
foo:www-data --> rwx:r-x
```

And the user can then do what they like with that file/directory.

But when I use PHP to create a file or directory the permissions generated are

```
www-data:www-data --> rwx:r-x
```

Which then **doesn't** allow the user to do what they like with that file/directory.

So I have two options:

1. I have thought about adding the user `foo` to the group `www-data` but I have multiple virtual hosts and I don't want them to be able to edit each other's virtual domains (if that is even possible?!)
2. I have also thought about when creating the folder using PHP I will set the permissions to `777` but that seems like a big 'no no' (is it?)

What should I do?!

Comment: I don't understand what you say in your first option... does every vhost have a different user?

Answer (score 0):

You could use phps chown() function to change the owner after creating the directory. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.chown.php. But you may need special privileges to successfully use the function, which may introduce a security issue.

---

Another option is the use of suEXEC in combination with [SuexecUserGroup](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_suexec.html) if you are running php-fpm (via FCGI instead of mod-php). In your virtual host file you will have to assign a user and a group to a virtual host via

```
SuexecUserGroup exampleuser examplegroup
```

With this directive activated all new directories and files created by php will have the specified user/group combination. Thats how a known webhost from germany does this, see the [uberspace documentation](https://wiki.uberspace.de/webserver:htaccess#hintergrunddie_virtualhost_konfiguration) (german only). More general information can be found [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/suexec.html).

Using this solution you would avoid many security risks automatically. No need for 777 permissions, no possibility to see each others files etc.

Because with this approach, every user will have his own php instance running, its very easy and secure to allow them to use different php interpreter versions or own php.ini files.

Answer (score 0):

What you actually want to do is run different virtual hosts as different users. This is a link to some helpful answers for nginx:https://serverfault.com/questions/370820/user-per-virtual-host-in-nginx

The same concepts apply to Apache.

Edit:
The answers weren't clear to me when I read them, and there's a lot of info in the comments. The second answer by @Ricalsin is very informative and had a link that I used. Be sure to restart php-fps and nginx!